# Is it possible to add a custom class to QStandardItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know if its possible to add a custom class to QStandardItem . I currently do something like this

```
QStandardItem* item_text=  new QStandardItem();
item_text->setText(msg.c_str());
```

Now suppose I had a class `foo` that did not inherit from QVariant is it possible to store it in QStandardItem ? If so how would I store it and then retrieve it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
    QStandardItem::setData ( const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::UserRole + 1 )
```

You can use,something like this:

```
   QStandardItem item;
   item.setData(QVariant(MyClass),Qt::UserRole);
```

So i think what you need to do is to typecast your custom class to QVariant(as shown above) and set the corresponding role ,like I used UserRole.
Then while extracting the data you can typecast it back to your custom class.

Also you can save in userrole by incrementing it something like:

```
  item.setData(QVariant(MyClass),Qt::UserRole + 1000);
  item.setData(QVariant(MyNewClass),Qt::UserRole + 1001);
```

and so on.
  Hope it helps. :)